# DSE: Activating OLAP

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-studio

I have installed using a single DataCenter with Analytics, Graph and Search enabled through OpsCenter and wish to activate OLAP Queries using DSEStudio.I have also managed to do this on the sparkmaster node using gremlin using the following DSE guide [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/northwindDemoGraphSnapshot.html), but I am unable to run the same commands on DSE Studio with commands that has `:` such as`:remote config alias g database.a`. When this commands is run the error encountered is shown below

**Error**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.contorl.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:startupfailed:Script95.groovy:1:unexcepted token:@line1, columns1.
:remote config alias g GeneratedGraph.a
^
1 error
```

I have checked that Spark, Cassandra and Solr is running on the nodes installed. Any advise on steps I may have missed will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In Studio, under the run arrow, select Execute using analytic engine (Spark) before running." 
The drop-down is "real-time" by default, you should switch it to "Analytic"
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/quickStart/graphQSTOC.html